# Text area display problem in IE7 Browser

Tags: textarea

In our application we have a text area with row size 20 .
Earlier when we were using the IE6 browser then the text area was displaying properly on screen but after switching over IE7 browser we have seen that after filling up 20 lines  a active scroll bar start displaying with text area and only 19 lines are displaying in text area and 1 line is hiding in scroll bar and to check that 1 line we have to use the scroll bar. Please note that our text area's row size is 20 which means it should display 20 lines without active scrollbar which was happening in IE6 browser but not happening in IE7.

We are not sure whether anybody else have faced this kind of problem before.

Answer (score 1):

Guys..as of now we have done some workaround by using bottom-padding to text area.....by doing this all the contents are dislaying properly in text area boxes but still the active  scroll bar remains with the text area box.

let us know if you guys having any different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a CSS rule somewhere setting the physical height of the `textarea`?

Comment: No we don't have any CSS rule to set the physical height of text area. Infect if you create a simple text area in HTML format with row size = 3 and open it in IE7 then you will see that as your enter 3rd line you will get a active scroll bar with your text area.

Answer (score 0):

You might try applying the Overflow property to the CSS for the text area.  Try overflow:auto; or overflow:hidden;.  The last one will eliminate all scroll bars though.  You could also try changing the border-width: thin;

Comment: Actually I need that scroll bar in text area but the thing is if the text area's row size is 20 then it should show the 20 rows without any scroll bar but what is happening that as I entered 20th line the text area started displaying the scroll bar and to see that 20th line we have to use the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using overflow:scroll, make it as overflow:auto.i checked it,it's working!

Answer (score 0):

In spite of using row="20", try to use a fixed height for the textarea. And don't forget to put line-height. It will definitely solve this problem.